# How to keep the data on page refreshing in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code

```
$cookieStore.put('profileData', $scope.profileData);
            var profileData = $cookieStore.get('profileData');
            $scope.init = function(){
            var profileData = $cookieStore.get('profileData');
            if(profileData != undefined){

            }
        }
```

when i am page refreshing values are disappearing. So my question is whenever refreshing a page values could not be cleared.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I use localForage for retaining data. See https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage. Unfamiliar with $cookieStore. Are you injecting it into your controller correctly?

Comment: I think you will have to store data to any storage local/cookie whenever `keyup` is fired because while filling input field user may refresh page.

Comment: It might help you! http://embed.plnkr.co/doV9j7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) or the sessionStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("myItem", "myValue");
myVar = localStorage.getItem("myItem"));
```

Comment: If willing to use, localForage is superior; allowing users to storage any type of data, not just strings. https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/

Comment: I haven't used ever localForage, but for simple datas (string or stringified json) localStorage/sessionStorage is enough. Furthermore, I have not to deal with another external library. As usual: it depends. Sometimes you need something simple, sometime you need something more structurized. Thank you for the suggestion. I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, every time you refresh you are re initializing the cookie value with a $scope variable. It is the one creating problem..

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular cookies

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

you can know more [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Using [ngStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage).
You can use $localStorage and $sessionStorage services of the module to retain data after refresh.

$localStorage service keeps the data within the browser whereas $sessionStorage keeps the data within the tab.

You can go through the link for detailed description.
http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage